# Unable to position my jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I try to position my jQuery dialog at x:150px and y:150px (x,y) but always get my dialog at 0,0.

My code is :

```
$(function (){
    $(document.body).on('click', 'a.folder', function () {
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
        dialog.load(url, {}, 
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.append('some content here');
                dialog.dialog({
                    title: 'my title',
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    width: "auto",
                    maxWidth: "500",
                    position: [150, 150],
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Why is my position parameter ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruno said, the [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) property expects an object, which is interpreted by [jQuery UI Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).

If you want the element to be 150px from the top and 150px from the left of the document, you could do it like:

```
position: {my: "left top", at: "left+150 top+150", of: document}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kn3cw08u/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position), the `position` option accepts an `Object`, not an `Array`.

Example:

```
{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }
```

Try

```
position: { my: 'top+150', at: 'top+150' }
```